# How to deal with too much nested fields when creating a table on Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm on Bigquery, I'm trying to create a table from a Parquet file.
I got this error:

```
Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: Field 'produit.elements.bag.array_element.couche_matiere.bag.array_element.composition_coloris.bag.array_element.composition.bag.array_element.libelle_compo.bag.array_element.code_langue' is nested too deeply. It has definition level 17 while maximum allowed definition level is 15.
```

I understand that I have too much (17) nested fields but I have to deal with this schema.

Do anyone have any idea about how to deal with that?

Thank you

Comment: how about revisit schema of your table? :o)

Comment: Can you show sample data and schema (without sensitive content) similar to your parquet file?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Unfortunately I have to deal with this schema, I can't change it for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to transform your parquet file to ORC format.

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm. Good tips :)

Here is the code I used to convert it:


`df = spark.read.parquet("/user/hive/warehouse/dataraw.db/styles")

df.write.mode("overwrite").orc("/tmp/styles_orc")`